# PHP: Parsing data within multidimensional array

Tags: php, parsing, multidimensional-array

I have an array which looks like this:

```
    Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => TE=140414100000  cd  =AB1234  ggg   =1234567  gbh  =2
            [7] => nd: DA1AAAAAAAAAA: TD = 140414: 
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => TE=140414100000  cd  =AB1234  ggg   =1234567  ghb  =2
            [7] => nd: DA1AAAAAAAAAA: TD = 140414:
        )
)
```

what I am trying to acomplish is to parse data within each sub array and create a new multidimensional array with the parsed data.

Example: *the data in parentheses below is what should be returned in new multidimensional array*

```
    Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => te=(140414100000)  cd  =AB(1234)  ggg   =1234567  ghb  =2
            [7] => nd: DA(1)(AAAAAAAAAA): TD = (140414): 
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => te=(140414100000)  cd  =AB(1234)  ggg   =1234567  ghb  =2
            [7] => nd: DA(2)(BBBBBBBBBB): TD = (140414):
        )
)
```

What I want to return:

```
    Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 140414100000
            [1] => 1234
            [2] => 1
            [3] => AAAAAAAAAA
            [4] => 140414
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 140414100000
            [1] => 1234
            [2] => 2
            [3] => BBBBBBBBBB
            [4] => 140414
        )
).
```

So my question is what would be the best way to acomplish this?

This is what I have come up with. It works, however is seems very inefficient as it adds a lot of empty arrays which have to be cleaned up.

```
foreach($new as $key => $val){
            foreach($val as $res){
                preg_match_all('%te=([0-9]{12})\s%',$res,$matches);
                $out[$key][] = $matches[1][0];
                preg_match_all('%cd\s+=AB([0-9]{4})%',$res,$matches);
                $out[$key][] = $matches[1][0];
                preg_match_all('%nd:\sDA([0-9]{1})%',$res,$matches);
                $out[$key]['node'] = $matches[1][0];
                preg_match_all('%nd:\sDA[0-9]{1}([a-zA-Z]{10,14}):%',$res,$matches);
                $out[$key]['rset'] = $matches[1][0];
                preg_match_all('%td\s=\s([0-9]{6}):%',$res,$matches);
                $out[$key]['trdt'] = $matches[1][0];
            }
        }
        foreach($out as $v){
            $v = array_values(array_filter($v));
            $return[] = $v; 
        }
        return $return;
```

Thanks in advance.

UPDATED:
This worked and is much more efficient. Thanks for the example Shankar

```
foreach($new as $key => $val){
            $v = implode('', $val);
            preg_match_all("%te=([0-9]{12})|cd\s+=AB([0-9]{4})|nd:\sDA([0-9]{1})|([A-Z]{3,7}):|td=\s([0-9]{6}):%",$v,$matches);
            $new_array[$key]['time'] = $matches[1][0];
            $new_array[$key]['code'] = $matches[2][1];
            $new_array[$key]['sp'] = $matches[3][2];
            $new_array[$key]['rset'] = $matches[4][3];
            $new_array[$key]['trfdt'] = $matches[5][4];
        }
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($new_array);
        echo "</pre>";
```

Comment: Guess this involves array functions with regex. Could you show us what have you tried?

Comment: @ICanHasCheezburger is right: you should not just dump your problem here and expect others to do your work for your. That is not how this place works. You should only ask here if you are really stuck with your own attempts to implement what you require. So where is your implementation so far? Please post that code!

Comment: @arkascha Thank you for the advice, and yes I'm aware of how this the place works. I have not posted much but have done my fair share of lurking. I posted what I have which is working, but my question is simply.. is there a better way to do it.

Comment: Sure, all fine. Now after your edit, where you posted the code we asked for, this question does make sense.

Comment: @codekloud, omg why do you `preg_match_all()` again and again ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loop through your array and `implode` each array element and use a `preg_match_all()` to capture all the entries bewteen `(` and `)` and then pass those matches to your new array.

```
foreach($arr as $k=>$arr1)
{
    $v = implode('',$arr1);
    preg_match_all('^\((.*?)\)^', $v, $matches);
    $new_arr[]=$matches[1];
}
print_r($new_arr);
```

<kbd>[Working Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/yxaPDL)</kbd>

Comment: I edited my post to show code using your method and it works and is much cleaner than what I came up with. Thanks!